# Problems with moving character in python game with mouse

Tags: python, pygame, mouse

I'm making a point'n'click game in pygame. I could implement keyboard movement, but my character can't be controlled by mouse. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/grzegorz/Pulpit/Gierka/gierka.py", line 19, in 
<module>
class Player(pg.Rect):
File "/home/grzegorz/Pulpit/Gierka/gierka.py", line 34, in Player
if event.key == BUTTON_LEFT:
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Here is the source code:

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.locals import *
from pynput.mouse import Controller  

pg.init()

mouse = Controller()
pg.mouse.set_cursor(*pg.cursors.broken_x)
pg.display.set_caption("White Collar: The Game")

display = pg.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))
pg.init()
character = pg.image.load("hero.png")
background = pg.image.load("obraz1.png")
characterx = 300
charactery = 300

class Player(pg.Rect):
while True:
    display.blit(background, (0, 0))
    display.blit(character, (characterx, charactery))
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_a:
                characterx -= 40
            if event.key == K_d:
                characterx += 40
            if event.key == K_w:
                charactery -= 40
            if event.key == K_s:
                charactery += 40
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.key == BUTTON_LEFT:
                characterx -= 10
                charactery -= 10
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            exit()
    pg.display.update()
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to move my character with a mouse - keyboard already works, but I have no idea how to implement mouse in this game

Comment: what's your error? Try to add some details

Comment: When I used snippets to implement mouse events, game stopped running.

Comment: add errors that you see when running your code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: A bit more detail would be useful

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells you that the `Event` object has no `key` attribute. Take a look at [pygame's documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html):

> Events that come from the system will have a guaranteed set of member attributes based on the type. The following is a list event types with their specific attributes.
>
> ```
> QUIT              none
> ACTIVEEVENT       gain, state
> KEYDOWN           key, mod, unicode, scancode
> KEYUP             key, mod
> MOUSEMOTION       pos, rel, buttons
> MOUSEBUTTONUP     pos, button
> MOUSEBUTTONDOWN   pos, button
> JOYAXISMOTION     joy, axis, value
> JOYBALLMOTION     joy, ball, rel
> JOYHATMOTION      joy, hat, value
> JOYBUTTONUP       joy, button
> JOYBUTTONDOWN     joy, button
> VIDEORESIZE       size, w, h
> VIDEOEXPOSE       none
> USEREVENT         code
> ```

As you can see, when the `Event` is of type `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`, it hase no `key` attribute, but a `pos` and a `button` attribute.

So if you want to check if the left mouse button is clicked, check for `event.button == 0`.

When you run into this kind of errors, use a debugger to inspect the object in question (or use simply `print` statements) and look up the documentation.